# Is there a way automatically to resize MediaWiki images depending on screen size?

Tags: image, mediawiki, resize, image-resizing

MediaWiki [pictures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aPicture_tutorial) can be set to a certain size with simple formatting.

However, [tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aTable) will resize on the fly depending on the browser / screen size.

Can images be made to resize like tables?

(Images *inside* tables does not work!)

Comment: I had the same question and saw from the answers below that you cannot have several pics with different relative sizes. So I wrote a mediawiki extension: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AdaptiveThumb

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk: suggest you add that as a new answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same question and saw from the answers above (now they are below) that you cannot have several pics with different relative sizes. So I wrote a mediawiki extension allowing this: http://mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AdaptiveThumb

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic resizing as the browser is resized:
Put the next line at the begining of the css file: **.\skins\common\shared.css**

```
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9; /* ie8 */ }
```

Each resizable image will be placed inside a `<div></div>`

```
<div>[[Image:MyImage.png]]</div>
```

Read more here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help_talk:Images

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a CSS hack.

Mediawiki allows you to include some variables like alt-text, including in that variable a special string such as `w100` or `resizeable` will allow you to target the element with CSS:

```
img[alt=~w100] { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
```

Do note that since you are using `alt` for things it's not meant to be used and `!important` in the CSS (because MW sets the size as an element style), this is to be avoided as much as possible and meant to be used as last resort.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, there is no easy way to do this.  It could conceivably be done with a bunch of fiddly Javascript, but I'm not aware of anybody having tried this and the implementation would not be trivial.

Comment: you will find there where to report bugs in case it does not work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. The long answer is that you would have to write JavaScript that can determine the user's screen resolution and store it in a cookie.. This would have to be done most likely in common.js so that with the exception of the one in a billion user that has never been to the site and manages to navigate directly to the page with the dynamically sized image (I hope you're not going to put something like that on your main page), that information will already be there when they get to the page.  The page could then use those variables to set the size to be `{{#expr:(File height * % of screen you want it to take)*(screen height)}}x{{#expr:(File width * % of screen you want it to take)*(screen width)}}px`.  The host of my wiki says he is in the process of writing a new extension that may be able to do that as part of a request for a `<div style="overflow-x: scroll; width: {{#expr:(File width * % of screen you want it to take)*(screen width)}}px;">` section I want to make.  If you find something else before me, please update this post so I can see it.  Thanks. :D

Comment: Why would you even need to write user's screen resolution into a cookie? It's something that's live and changes on the fly. One second it's 1400px, the other second it can be 600px.