# How do I scale an image's width to a percentage of the window with MediaWiki?

Tags: html, css, image, scale, mediawiki

With html I can scale an image's width to a percentage of the available window like this:

```
<img src=whatever.png width=50% />
```

With mediawiki this seems to be impossible (if you do not allow html injections). Is it really? Don't tell me I have to write a mediawiki extension ;)

Note the CSS answer from [Is there a way automatically to resize MediaWiki images depending on screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078157/is-there-a-way-automatically-to-resize-mediawiki-images-depending-on-screen-size) is not a solution. I want to have different images in one page with different percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier for myself I wrote a mediawiki extension that allows

- alignment
- relative size
- links under images
- captions like for thumbnails

It's here: https://github.com/tstaerk/adaptivethumb

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible to apply [the CSS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078157/is-there-a-way-automatically-to-resize-mediawiki-images-depending-on-screen-size/22805793#22805793) to specific images by tagging them with a custom class name.  That is, you'd add something like the following to your MediaWiki:Common.css page:

```css
img.halfwidth {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

and then use wiki markup like this:

```
[[File:Myimage.jpg|class=halfwidth]]
```

(Note that specifying a class name on an image like this requires MediaWiki 1.20+.  If, for some reason, you need to do this on an older MediaWiki version, you can instead change the CSS selector to e.g. `.halfwidth img`, and the wiki syntax to `<div class="halfwidth">[[File:Myimage.png]]</div>`.)

Comment: really a great answer and it answers my question - however I have started developing https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AdaptiveThumb that allows you to set a width in percent and will allow you to link to a site when clicking onto the image.